# How to get older tag of a git repository in elixir via mix file

Tags: git, elixir, elixir-mix

I am trying to install an older version of a library [cqerl](https://github.com/matehat/cqerl) through mix.exs file in elixir.

This is how my code looks:

```
 defp deps do
    [
      {:cqerl, git: "https://github.com/matehat/cqerl.git",tag: "v0.9.0"}
    ]
```

But for some reason, instead of installing the 0.9.0 tag, it is installing the latest tag.

I would like to know what's wrong with my code and how can I correctly pull the right tag from Cqerl repository.

TIA :)

Comment: Did you make sure to do `mix deps.get` after adding `tag: "v0.9.0"` to `mix.exs`?

Comment: yes. I even deleted the deps folder all together, then did mix deps.get and mix deps.compile. It is getting the latest 1.0 version of cqerl.

Comment: What's the output of `cd deps/cqerl && git rev-parse HEAD` after `mix deps.get`? I'm getting `e05a57019c7476621f7295d76ed656e6e1401a0e` which is what `v0.9.0` points to according to Github.

Comment: I was getting a different output first. But once I deleted the mix.lock file and deps.get, I started getting same as this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to delete the mix.lock file as well along with the deps folder. So, basically I did the following:

```
rm mix.lock
rm -rf deps/
mix deps.get
```

That way, it worked.

I am using Elixir version 1.2.4 right now, and this is a bug in mix. I came to know later that it has been fixed in master via elixir-lang irc.

Answer (score 0):

after modifying repo's tag in `mix.exs`, you should execute `mix deps.update cqerl`, which would update `mix.lock` and use the modified tag.